# Display three divs by order absolute than fixed than relative

Tags: javascript, css, position, fixed, absolute

I have some problems when rendering on only app(iOS) NOT website:
I have to use pure Javascript without any other libraries.

```
<div class="header" style="position:fixed; z-index: 99;"></div>
<div class="content" style="position:relative">
  <div class="cover" style="position:absolute; z-index:999;"></div>
   //some text content
</div>
```

The Cover div didn't display overlapping Header. What can I do to that?

I want that initially user will see Cover first, then scroll up then see fixed Header and eventually Content.

I dont want to change the HTML, because when I put header in content div, header usually jumps and take moment to back the correct position when scrolling content div.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: _"Absolute Div didn't overlap Header"_ you didn't tell it to. --- _"How can I do that?"_ look up _CSS_. --- _"destructure the HTML"_ what does this mean?

Comment: `z-index` only works with elements in the same parent container, since `header` and `cover` are not in the same parent their z-index will not change how they overlap. With your current structure you would need to put `z-index` on `content` not `cover`

Comment: but I set z-index of content  greater than header, I only see text of header without its CSS. In this case, the Cover displays OK. Can you recommend a  nother solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give #content a z-index property, too. Say, 100.

The problem looks like z-index context. z-index is not a global value - it is relative to it's parent. You have #header with z-index:99, and it's sibling #content with z-index:auto(say 1 for argument's sake). #header always overlaps #content, and its children.

Comment: When I add #content a z-index: 100,
the order displaying now is Cover > text content > header

See my screenshot:
https://gyazo.com/c64087da5e6b590a06619be8116e38c8

Comment: @ĐìnhLâm can you post your CSS? There could be several things going on here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute property to **cover** class, relative to **content** className that means, it position will change according to content class. Remove **relative** property to content class, add wrapeer to all header and content className.

```
<div style="position:relative">
      <div class="header" style="position:fixed; z-index: 99;"></div>
      <div class="content" >
          <div class="cover" style="position:absolute; z-index:999;"></div>
          //some text content
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My header and content has parent div is body, but I have many html files with the same structure, so I try to find a way without changing HTML. Anyways thanks :)

Comment: @ĐìnhLâm Use `scroll` event and change styles according to your custom theming.